# Make a new line in Stringlist if the current line contains too much text?

Tags: java, api, minecraft, bukkit

So I currently have my stringlist, where the user can edit what gets put into it, as long as its a string. So with shorter text this works fine, but when the text starts becoming longer and longer, the tooltip i use the stringlist for will take up too much of the screen and make things look ugly. So i want to make a new line for a stringlist for each specific amount of characters so it doesnt get messy. Here is my current test that i've been running for it:

```
'Salamander specializes in disguising in the green woods, mainly in oak forests salamanders will hide and lure to wait for your loot, they will then jump out and do a sneak attack. Be prepared!'
```

I obtain that information with this:

```
lore.add(kitConfig.getString("kits." + kitName + ".description"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `String` inside the lore `ArrayList<String>` is displayed on a new line. You could write a method which splits a `String` into segments, and returns an `ArrayList` containing those parts that you can then set as the new lore. Here's an example of how this might look:

```
public static ArrayList<String> splitLore(String text, int characters) {
    ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>(); // Create the ArrayList that will contain the lore lines
    if (text.length() <= characters) { // If the line of text is short enough (doesn't need to be split)...
        lore.add(text); // Add the entire line to the list and return it
    } else { // If the line is longer and needs to be split into at least two lines...
        int beginIndex = 0; // A "begin index" where each substring or segment will begin
        while (beginIndex <= text.length() - 1) { // If the index is not larger than the last character index in the line of text...
            lore.add(text.substring(beginIndex, Math.min(beginIndex + characters, text.length()))); // Add the segment
            beginIndex += characters;
            // This will also add any trailing segments at the end of the line that are shorter than the character limit
        }
    }
    return lore;
}
```

Example usage:

```
String lore = "This is a long description of an item's lore that needs to be broken down"
ItemMeta meta = // ... Get the ItemMeta object of an ItemStack
meta.setLore(splitLore(lore, 10)); // Splits the single line into multiple ones containing 10 or less characters
```

This method is not very "smart" and will cut words off, creating text lines that don't look very pretty or are hard to read.

To make the lore more pleasant to read, you could split the line of text into "words", and then try to group them in such a way that no line exceeds the "soft" character limit too drastically. The example method below won't cut apart words, although it also won't forcibly split extremely long words that take up more than an entire line.

```
public static ArrayList<String> splitLoreNicely(String text, int characters) {
    ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] words = text.split(" "); // Get the "words" in the line of text by splitting the space characters
    int wordsUsed = 0; // A counter for how many words have been placed in lines so far
    while (wordsUsed < words.length) { // Repeat this process until all words have been placed into separate lines
        String line = ""; // The line that will be added to the lore list
        for (int i = wordsUsed; i < words.length; i++) { // For each remaining word in the array
            if (line.length() + words[i].length() >= characters) { // If adding the next word exceeds or matches the character limit...
                line += words[i]; // Add the last word in the line without a space character
                wordsUsed++;
                break; // Break out of this inner loop, since we have reached/exceeded the character limit for this line
            } else { // If adding this word does not exceed or match the character limit... 
                line += words[i] + " "; // Add the word with a space character, continue for loop
                wordsUsed++;
            }
        }
        lore.add(line); // Add the line of text to the list
    }
    return lore;
}
```